# История посещений сайтов на компьютере скриптом powershell?

Tags: powershell

История посещений сайтов на компьютере скриптом powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так (это даст список посещенных сайтов):

```
powershell -noexit "ipconfig /displaydns | select-string 'Record Name' | foreach-object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[-1]   } | Sort | Out-Gridview"
```

Либо смотреть, какой браузер стоит в системе, где он хранит историю, извлекать ее оттуда, и как-то анализировать.

Comment: Спасибо. Использовал в PowerShell так: ipconfig /displaydns | select-string "Имя записи" | Sort  >> d:\text.txt